# How to prevent command prompt from closing automatically after its getting an error with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, command-prompt

I'm making a python app.
Using pyinstaller, I made my app exe file.
When I execute it, it it gets some errors, the command prompt close automatically.
I don't want it to close.

When it doesn't get any error, the command prompt doesn't close.
How can I prevent it from closing auntomatically after the code getting some errors?

Comment: one vanilla approach could be to the put the code in a `try except` block

Comment: write code that doesn't crash

Comment: Thank you guys. I could solve the problem